# Recall didSelectItemAt on collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my project, there is label inside the collectionView cell that when user taps on it, the color of the label will change
I did that with these codes

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CaseCell {
         cell.selectCell()
      }
   }
   
   public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CaseCell {
         cell.deSelectCell()
      }
   }
```

Now, I want when user open this page and he/she already tap on any of them before, the `selectCell` will be called again.
I can say in the `cellForRowAt`if the cell is the selected cell, call that function, but it wont behave like `didSelectItemAt` and `didSelectItemAt`. So how can I set when the page gets opened, it call `didSelectItemAt` and tap on the specific index? Then I when I add on the another cell, didSelectItemAt is also called.
Thank you so much

---

here is my sulation, I don't know it's acceptable or not

for example, I set the selected row to index.row == 2

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(reusableType: CaseCell.self, indexPath: indexPath)
      cell.configure(text: cases[indexPath.row])
      if indexPath.row == 2 {
         cell.selectCell()
      } else {
         cell.deSelectCell()
      }
      return cell
   }
   
   public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CaseCell {
         
         for index in 0..<cases.count {
            let index = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            let deselctCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) as? CaseCell
            deselctCell?.deSelectCell()
         }
         
         cell.selectCell()
      }
   }
```

Comment: You can implement this via model class. It's much easier to control any desire behaviour.

Comment: @Nizzam It makes it very complicated, my view is simple, its data source is an array of string and I want to pre-select one the cell

Comment: It's easy to debugging even the view is simple

Comment: Currently I don't have enough time for that. I added a solution, do you think it's good enough for now

Comment: It's not that hard. Btw, I think your solution might have a problem when scrolling occur (small screen).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use both `didSelect` and `didDeselect` method to handle the selection and deselection of cells instead of interating through the entire collection of cells.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CaseCell {
        cell.deSelectCell()
    }
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CaseCell {
        cell.selectCell()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a property for the currently selected index path. You can set it to a default value

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath? = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
```

The most reliable way is to modify the cells **only** in `cellForItemAt`, nowhere else. Depending on `selectedIndexPath` select or deselect the sell.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(reusableType: CaseCell.self, indexPath: indexPath)
   cell.configure(text: cases[indexPath.row])
   indexPath == selectedIndexPath ? cell.selectCell() : cell.deSelectCell()
   return cell
}
```

In `didSelectItemAt` change the value of `selectedIndexPath` and reload both the current and the previous cell.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
{
    if selectedIndexPath != indexPath  {
        let indexPathsToReload = selectedIndexPath == nil ? [indexPath] : [selectedIndexPath!, indexPath]
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPathsToReload)
    } else {
        selectedIndexPath = nil
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
}
```

`didDeselectedItemAt` is not needed.

The code considers also the case of an empty selection. If you don't want this declare `selectedIndexPath` as non-optional

```
var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
```

and change `didSelectItemAt` to

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
{
    guard selectedIndexPath != indexPath else { return }
    let indexPathsToReload = [selectedIndexPath, indexPath]
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPathsToReload)
}
```